# How can this program be changed so it's able to work with all types of lists and so the output is slightly more accurate?

Tags: python

Here is the practice project I am working on from the book Automate the Boring Stuff with Python.

---

Table Printer

Write a function named printTable() that takes a list of lists of strings and displays it in a well-organized table with each column right-justified. Assume that all the inner lists will contain the same number of strings. For example, the value could look like this:

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]
```

Your printTable() function would print the following:

```
  apples Alice  dogs
 oranges   Bob  cats
cherries Carol moose
  banana David goose
```

Hint: Your code will first have to find the longest string in each of the inner lists so that the whole column can be wide enough to fit all the strings. You can store the maximum width of each column as a list of integers. The printTable() function can begin with colWidths = [0] * len(tableData), which will create a list containing the same number of 0 values as the number of inner lists in tableData. That way, colWidths[0] can store the width of the longest string in tableData[0], colWidths[1] can store the width of the longest string in tableData[1], and so on. You can then find the largest value in the colWidths list to find out what integer width to pass to the rjust() string method.

---

Here is what I have so far and it works but the output is slightly different and some values are hard-coded so different lists wouldn't work in it:

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]

def printTable(tableData, rightWidth):
    colWidths = [0] * len(tableData)
    for i in range(len(colWidths)):
        colWidths[i] = len(max(tableData[i], key=len))

    for y in range(len(tableData[0])):
        for x in range(len(tableData)):
            print(tableData[x][y].rjust(rightWidth), end='')
        print()

printTable(tableData, 8)
```

Comment: As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0):

this has been a tricky one for me, too.
However, I find this solution works pretty well.

The magic is to turn around the indexes on the list, a feature not included in the book until this point, which makes it way harder than this really is.

Note that the (LIST[0]) is the flaw of this code, since it would not tolerate lists of unequal sub-list length.

Here you go (the commented out sections may be enabled by you to see what the individual steps are doing in regards to numbers):

```
def printTable(table):
colWidth = [0] * len(table)
for i in range(len(table)):
    # print('number of item\'s in sub-list ' + str(i) + ': ' + str(len(table[i])))
    columnwidth = []
    for j in range(len(table[i])):
        columnwidth.append(len(table[i][j]))
        # print(str(len(table[i][j])))
        # print('columnwidth:' + str(columnwidth))
    # print('column\'s ' + str(i) + ' width: ' + str(max(columnwidth)))
    colWidth[i] = (max(columnwidth))
# print(colWidth)
for i in range(len(table[0])): #works only with lists of the same number of items
    line = []
    for j in range(len(table)):
        line.append(str(table[j][i]).rjust(colWidth[j]))
    print(' '.join(line))

printTable(tableData)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to google how to transpose the a list of lists, but below is what I had

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
         ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
         ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]
def printTable(a):
b=[]
c=[]
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    for j in range (0,len(a[i])):
        b.append(len(a[i][j]))
    b.sort(reverse=True)
    c.append(int(b[0]))
    b=[]
d=list(map(list, zip(*a)))
for i in range (0,len(d)):
    for j in range (0, len(d[i])):
        print(d[i][j].rjust(c[j]),end =' ')
    print()
printTable(tableData)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at answers above and will try to implement on my end. I've written the following with success though it isn't as concise as the above solutions it works and is clear.

```
def printTable(table):
    # Step 1: Find longest strings from each list and 
    # save as a new list called 'width'

    colWidth=[]
    count=0

    for i in range(len(table)):
        tempList=[]
        for i in range(len(table[count])):
            tempList.insert(i, len(table[count][i]) )

        #insert temp list variable to save char totals
        colWidth.insert( count, tempList ) 
        count += 1

    for i in range(len(colWidth)):
        colWidth[i] = max(colWidth[i])

    print(colWidth)

    # Step 2: Transpose table
    # Consider flow control to move through each row
    # Consider flow control to iterate each value on each line

    item=0
    for getRows in range(len(table[item])):
        print()
        for getItems in range(len(table)) :
            print( table[getItems][getRows].rjust(colWidth[getItems]+4), end='' )
        item +=1

    print()

    printTable(tableData)
```

Comment: As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.